# How to make a pre-existing tensorflow variable_scope apply to ops?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

The following works as expected:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.variable_scope('layer123'):
    v = tf.get_variable('v', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(3., tf.float32))
    w = v * 2

print(v.name)    # Prints layer123/v:0
print(w.name)    # Prints layer123/mul:0
```

However, when I try the following instead:

```
with tf.variable_scope('layer123'):
    v = tf.get_variable('v', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(3., tf.float32))

# There might be some code here (perhaps even a different function), but not necessarily

with tf.variable_scope('layer123'):
    w = v * 2

print(v.name)    # Prints layer123/v:0
print(w.name)    # Prints layer123_1/mul:0
```

Here, the variable `w` lives in a new `variable_scope` auto-named `layer123_1`. How do I prevent this behaviour? Setting `reuse=True` in the second `with` statement didn't help, as expected.

I want to have `w.name == 'layer123/mul:0'`, especially when the multiply op is not defined immediately after (i.e. without exiting the scope) the variable `v` is defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by reusing the scope object. For example,

```
with tf.variable_scope('layer123') as scope:
    v = tf.get_variable('v', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(3., tf.float32))
with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    w = v * 2
```

For more information, see the [documentation on sharing variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope).